# Convert Toast message to text

Tags: android, text-to-speech, toast

How can I convert this TOAST message to voice in Android?

**Example**

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am enter code here" +positive[+ position]+ " always", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Are you trying to have Android speak a String?

Comment: yes, that ever is the Toast message popup that should be converted to voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView wordView = (TextView)view; String wordChosen = (String) wordView.getText(); Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am " + positive[+position] + " always", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //tts.speak("I am" + blank +position+" always", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); tts.speak("You chose, you are "+wordChosen+" today and always", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

First import the package

```
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
```

Then initialize

```
private TextToSpeech tts;
  tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

Finally make a function like this

```
  private void speakOut() {

    String text = txtText.getText().toString();

    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Woops. I forgot, you'll also need to define an onInit function

```
 public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}
```

In this example I used an `onClickListener` to call this function, using a button. Modify it to how you want to call this function when you toast a message.

Just make the String `text` as your toast message. In the example above `txtText` was an editText. Modify as per your requirement

Comment: TextView wordView = (TextView)view;
             
                String wordChosen = (String) wordView.getText();
                


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am " + positive[+position] + "  always", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                //tts.speak("I am" + blank +position+"  always", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                tts.speak("You chose, you are  "+wordChosen+"  today and always", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);